# How to have button change code already written?

Tags: html

Here is just an example:

```
<html>
<p><center>Background Color: <input type="text" name="image"> <button>Go</button> </center></p>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
<html>
```

How would I make it so when you press the go button, the text in the input changes the powderblue to whatever is written there?

Comment: Javascript will do the trick. Have a research regarding that. Also, go over jquery.

Answer (score 1):

A script from `jquery` will do the trick. See below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<p><center>Background Color: <input type="text" name="image" id="txtcolor"> 
<button id="btngo">Go</button> </center></p>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
</body>
<script>
$("#btngo").click(function(){
var color = $("#txtcolor").val();
$('body').css("background-color", ""+ color +"");
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps you might want to remove the `alert`? I assume you may have used it for debugging?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I tried typing in "yellow" and instead of changing the background to yellow, nothing happened.

Comment: @5Flux the code is working properly as given in the snippet, you might want to copy the snippet instead and then give it a try.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I removed the alert. And when I tried yellow, it's working for me.